# Wondering if I change the location of Windows boot loader it will show up in Ubuntu grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, windows-10

I have Ubuntu 21.10 desktop, Kali Linux, and Windows 10 on my computer. They are all installed on different drives. In my BIOS settings I set the default boot option to the drive with Ubuntu on it. When I boot into my computer the GRUB menu on the Ubuntu drive loads up. With Ubuntu and Kali Linux listed. I want Windows 10 also listed in GRUB so that I can easily boot into Windows 10 too instead of manually overriding the boot order in my BIOS settings. I am aware that Kali Linux also comes with GRUB installed, but it has the same issue that it won't detect the Windows 10 installation.

I already ran `sudo update-grub` and `sudo os-prober` GRUB found nothing. I looked into my BIOS and found that the Windows 10 Boot Manager was installed on the same drive as Ubuntu just in a different partition. How can I edit GRUB so that it locates the Windows 10 Boot Manager.